# URL роутинг на PHP

Tags: php, url, router

Начал разбираться в MVC PHP, после множества прочитанных статей и просмотренных видео уроков накатал каркас своего приложения. (Сразу попрошу не советовать использовать готовые решение, я хочу изобрести собственный велосипед, так мне легче во всем разобраться). Схема стандартная все запросы идут на index.php, в роутере разбираю URL на controller, action, params. Ну с этим проблем нет. URL получаются такого вида: http://localhost/categories/sport, где categories - имя контроллера, а sport - action. Потом создаю второй контроллер к примеру articles, URL - http://localhost/articles/football ну и все по прежней схеме. **Вопрос: как создать ссылку вида http://localhost/categories/sport/articles/football, или http://localhost/categories/sport/football.** Только так чтобы не писать все в одном контроллере.

Вот класс роутера:

```
<?php

class Router {

protected $uri;
protected $controller;
protected $action;
protected $params;
protected $route;
protected $method_prefix;
protected $language;

public function getUri() {
    return $this->uri;
}

public function getController() {
    return $this->controller;
}

public function getAction() {
    return $this->action;
}

public function getParams() {
    return $this->params;
}

public function getRoute() {
    return $this->route;
}

public function getMethodPrefix() {
    return $this->method_prefix;
}

public function getLanguage() {
    return $this->language;
}

public function __construct($uri) {
    $this->uri = urldecode(trim($uri, '/'));

    // Get defaults
    $routes = Config::get('routes');
    $this->route = Config::get('default_route');
    $this->method_prefix = isset($routes[$this->route]) ? $routes[$this->route] : '';
    $this->language = Config::get('default_language');
    $this->controller = Config::get('default_controller');
    $this->action = Config::get('default_action');

    $uri_parts = explode('?', $this->uri);

    // Get path like /lng/controller/action/param1/param2/
    $path = mb_substr($uri_parts[0], 14);

    $path_parts = explode('/', $path);

    if(count($path_parts)) {

        // Get route at first element
        if(in_array(strtolower(current($path_parts)), array_keys($routes))) {
            $this->route = strtolower(current($path_parts));
            $this->method_prefix = isset($routes[$this->route]) ? $routes[$this->route] : '';
            array_shift($path_parts);

        } elseif(in_array(strtolower(current($path_parts)), Config::get('languages'))) {
            $this->language = strtolower(current($path_parts));
            array_shift($path_parts);
        }

        //Get controller - next element of array
        if(current($path_parts)) {
            $this->controller = strtolower(current($path_parts));
            array_shift($path_parts);
        }

        //Get action
        if(current($path_parts)) {
            $this->action = strtolower(current($path_parts));
            array_shift($path_parts);
        }

        //Get params - all the rest
        $this->params = $path_parts;
    }
}

public static function redirect($location) {
    header("Location: $location");
    exit();
}

public static function notFound() {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    header('Status: 404 Not Found');

    return true;

}
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте порассуждать следующим образом. На выходе роутера у вас три значения: контроллер, экшен и параметры. А в ссылках, которые вы приводите, три или четыре элемента. Стало быть, два элемента - это контроллер и экшен, остальные - параметры. Вам нужно только определить, какая именно часть ссылки каким элементом является.

Comment: @cronfy Да, но если остальные параметры, то все придется делать в одном контроллере, например делать контроллер по умолчанию default controller, а в нем при условии что URL будет допустим http://localhost/category/sport/article/footbal - где category - action, а остальное параметры, если не найду решения буду делать так, но хотелось бы сделать так как это реализовано например в opencart, там для каждого елемента отдельный контроллер, да вот только не могу пока в коде разобраться.

Comment: Не обязательно, чтобы в url прямым текстом был прописан controller и action. Вам нужно просто создать правила, по которым url будет в них преобразовываться. Посмотрите, как это происходит во фреймворках - yii2, symfony, laravel, codeigniter. Не исходники, а именно принцип описания. Вы увидите, что механизм очень гибкий. После этого останется только понять, какая часть сайта каким контроллером обрабатывается, и написать правила. Все складывать в один контроллер, конечно, не нужно.

Comment: @cronfy, Спасибо за подсказку, пересмотрев кучу вариантов решил использовать **AltoRouter**, очень мне понравился, и если разобраться очень прост в использовании.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Закрываю вопрос, после долгих поисков нашел, и решил использовать **AltoRouter**, рекомендую всем: http://altorouter.com/